# Cannot boot computer after installing Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, ubuntu-16.04

I just got a refurbished computer and after installing Ubuntu, computer refuses to boot and instead displays screen with message:

"Insert system disk in drive. 
Press any key when ready...."

I tried reinstalling Linux twice (from a usb and from a cd) and the problem persists.

I have a Toshiba Portege R930 which originally had a Windows 7 and I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2

Any suggestions would be appreciated,

Thankyou xx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try changing the boot order so the hard disk is first.

2) Make sure the BIOS supports GRUB signatures.

3) Make sure the ISO is correct for your machine (is it 32-bit like your machine?, etc.)